# Need help narrowing a question

Tags: discussion

Originally, this *meta-posting* requested help with a posting that had been closed as too broad.  I got the help and revised the posting; the link to the revised posting is

[How to play streaming video from sites like HBO that require a Windows environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474055/how-to-play-streaming-video-from-sites-like-hbo-that-require-a-windows-environme)

Having done its job, this meta-posting has been retained so that G-Man's answer (below) can serve as a *somewhat generic* reference for others whose post is also considered too broad.

Comment: @αғsнιη appears to have been re-asked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474055/117549

Comment: Yes - I did re-ask the question, after getting help, much of which came from this posting.  Closing this posting now makes sense to me; the posting has done its job.

Comment: As a rebuttal idea, which the site admins might consider, I think that G-Man's answer provides a powerful *what to do* reference.  As such, I think that his answer should be preserved *somewhere*, perhaps by retaining this posting.  **Can this posting be closed without the posting being deleted?**

Comment: Why not just redirect the link in the question to the _new_, improved question?

Comment: @DopeGhoti good idea.  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You say “Several months ago I explored a variety of methods …” (in a comment)
  and “My understanding is that for at least the last 6 months,
  I could not do this from within any Linux OS.” 
  You make it sound you haven’t rechecked recently. 
  This might make people believe
  that you haven’t invested enough effort into the question. 
  People sometimes call a question “too broad” for this reason.
- And if you *haven’t* tried it in several months, do it again now. 
  You ask whether anything has changed recently. 
  Maybe something has, and it’s just sitting there, waiting for you to discover it.
- You can make the question more narrow by specifying *exactly* what you tried,
  *exactly* what happened, what possible solutions you are ruling out, and why.
- It might help if you said, broadly, where you are — i.e., what country. 
  (I guess you are in the US, but you don’t seem to say.)
- You say that you posted a question to our site a few months ago, but it was deleted. 
  (If it was similar to your current question, it was probably closed;
  and closed questions are automatically deleted under some conditions.) 
  Do you still have a copy of that question?

  Nothing is ever really deleted on Stack Exchange. 
  Do you still have the URL of your earlier question (i.e., a link to it)? 
  Try going [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/112507). 
  If that doesn’t work,
  try going into [your profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112507/user2661923?tab=questions) and clicking on “deleted recent questions”. 
  If you see an entry for your old question, see if you can get to it. 
  See if there are any relevant details there
  that you could add to your current question to make it clearer or more focused. 
  Post the link in any case;
  some of us have the privilege to see things that have been “deleted”.
- Your question looks like a document that’s covered in yellow sticky notes. 
  E.g.,

  > Extension: I did this because somebody suggested it.
  >   Explanation — *(and then you repeat the first paragraph, in more detail and clarity.)*
  >   And then there are more than 25 comments.

  Imagine you wrote a paper for school, or a report for your job,
  and you got it back with a note “Not good enough — try again.” 
  Would you resubmit the same paper
  with corrections scribbled in the margins and a pile of yellow sticky notes on it? 
  Of course not. 
  You would rewrite the entire paper to be coherent,
  with a logical sequence and structure. 
  You would include all the information that needs to be there, probably just once,
  at an appropriate level of detail.

  Edit your question the same way. 
  Don’t expect people to read the comments.

I’ve taken the liberty of drafting a suggested rewrite of your question. 
(I cannot guarantee that it would be received better
than the current version.) 
Use it, or not; add anything I missed; alter it if you want.

> I want to watch premium video on my computer. 
>   For example, hbo.com, cox.com, and many others provide paid video content. 
>   I can login to HBO using a browser ***(any browser?)***
>   on a Windows 7 or higher system
>   and stream their movies or watch cable TV. 
>   (I have a paid subscription. 
>   ***(Is this true?)*** 
>   I’m not trying to circumvent digital rights or do anything illegal or improper.)
>
> As recently as 18 months ago, this worked from Windows and Linux systems. 
>   About a year ago, this stopped working for Linux systems;
>   now you can do it only from Windows 7+. 
>   Here are things I’ve tried from my Fedora 26 machine:
>
> - Firefox: __________(error message)__________
> - Chrome: _________(what happened?)_________
> - (Browser #3): ____________(etc.)____________
> - (Technique/Trick X): __________(etc.)__________
> - (Suggestion by help.vivaldi.com): In my Chrome browser,
>     I was able to play the test page DRM videos, but HBO streaming still doesn’t work. 
>     __________(provide details, etc.)__________
> - Wine: __________(what happened?)__________
> - Running Windows in a VirtualBox VM causes overheating,
>     and causes moderate sound issues as well.
>
> My machine is dual boot, and so I can boot into Windows to watch video,
>   but this is inconvenient.
>
> Note that HBO programming is also restricted by location,
>   so, if you’re outside the US, you might not see the same interface that I see.
>
> How can I watch premium video content (e.g., that from HBO)
>   on my Linux (Fedora 26) machine without degraded quality or other problems?

Comment: very informative answer, thanks.

Comment: I think the aspect of circumventing evil restrictions of big media companies makes the question useful, which reasons the extra effort to save it, and the lenience reviewing it (inside the limits given by the rules).

Comment: TL;dr: when asking other for help, try to not ask them for stuff that you are capable of doing.