# My questions keep getting downvoted without any proper explanation as to why

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new to this site and I use StackOverflow as well as U&L very sparingly as I find that most of what I want to know is already there. However, one thing that I keep experiencing here which I did not face in StackOverflow is that my questions keep getting downvoted without any proper explanation as to what exactly is wrong with it.

To date, I have asked two questions on here and have not given any answers (except if you count the one on my own question) and both times my questions have been downvoted without literally anyone pointing out what was wrong with my question.

I have no qualms about rephrasing my question if I have been unclear or deleting my question if it is deemed off topic. If I am misinformed about something, I think pointing it out in the comments is a much better solution than downvoting without any explanation and leaving me to guess what I did wrong.

I can take the downvotes if I have asked a bad question, however, I was under the impression that someone from the community would at least tell me what I did wrong before doing so. That is at least what used to happen on SO. I have tried asking in the comments of my questions as to what I did wrong, but to no avail. I hope someone here can explain to me where am I going wrong.

Comment: I also think there is a growing problem of down vote abuse in this site and the system should find creational ways to deal with this awful problem. I just opened a meta thread about down voting abuse in a well phrased and well formatted question I opened here.

Comment: I think I have seen a question similar to mine here regarding the same problem a long time ago. I just don't understand the point of downvote abuse. Where is the fun in that?

Comment: In fact this meta question also had one downvote for some time

Comment: I faced a similar problem with closing votes. Two of my questions were closed. The first with a single critical comment (but unsure if the commenter even voted for closing!). The second one *without any* comment; some closing votes even came after I had accepted an answer! For this one I got it reopened without difficulty by flagging it for moderator attention. I think closing votes and question downvotes should be conditioned to making a comment beforehand. EDIT: I'm not a very new user (>1000 rep).

Comment: I see 2 of your questions on the main site, one of them has score 0, the other has score 1. These two questions don't seem bad for me. Did you delete your downvoted questions?

Comment: Suggested edit for this question. "downvoting without explanations do happen in StackOverFlow as well".

Comment: @peterh No, these are the questions that were downvoted. There got more upvotes than downvotes so it became alright, but if you see my reputation chart, you will see the downvotes are there

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan this was just the issue I was facing. I thought I was doing something wrong. If you feel this is a duplicate, you can vote to close this. I still feel that this question serves some purpose in illustrating how common this problem is.

Comment: @evilMinion, maybe. I did not face anything as such on SO. Some people were very harsh, and rude, but at least they did tell me where I was going wrong, which I think is important and that is not happening here

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita , well I experienced that myself in SO. Sadly I do not have proof as those questions were eventually deleted. I wish more people are aware of these netiquettes https://medium.freecodecamp.org/5-steps-to-become-a-better-stack-overflow-user-4ce85711c0f9  In this article he specifically mentions to write comments,especially when you downvote a question.

Comment: Please note that leaving a comment when downvoting very often opens the downvoting user to abuse. I almost always leave comments, and I very often need to deal with retaliatory downvtes or aggressive comments, complaints etc, which completely ignore the reasons I gave for downvoting. So while I get that it can be annoying to receive a downvote without a comment, one should also remember that leaving a comment when downvoting is rarely considered useful and usually is taken as an attack. Unfortunately.

Comment: @terdon First of all, kudos for your habit of leaving comments,explaining the downvotes. If you downvote (with a proper reason,hopefully) and provide a clear explanation to the downvote,and Still the others decide to attack that,then the problem is with them and not you right? We often get criticized for trying to do the right thing, but should we stop doing them because of that? ;)

Comment: I understand that some people can be irrationally abusive toward people trying to help them. But I think improving the quality of questions on this site (or anywhere else on stack exchange for that matter) comes first. If someone is verbally abusive, we can just walk away. And also there is also the option of never mentioning that you downvoted. One can just mention what is wrong. Someone who takes this as constructive will edit the question accordingly and the downvotes will automatically stop. The poster also never finds out who downvoted but gets to know what was wrong with the question.

Comment: @evilMinion, the link you shared is pretty much what I am feeling

Comment: I think that till a proper lasting solution is found, we could all just comment what is wrong with the question along with the downvote, but never mention that we did downvote it.

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita if you leave a comment on a post that has a downvote, the OP will assume you downvoted 9 times out of 10. This has happened to me _very_ often. More importantly, you have posted 2 questions and each received one downvote. Don't you think you might be exaggerating when you say your questions "keep getting downvoted"? I mean, all it takes is one user having a bad day to cast two downvotes. I don't see how you can draw any conclusions from only 2 data points.

Comment: @JohnDoea's Can you post a link to your meta post? (Or least indicate which site it was posted on (not on this meta site?).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I already deleted it after it itself was downvoted and marked as a "duplicate". Go figure. I am outta here...

Comment: I have a question here which got downvoted and voted to be closed within minutes of me posting the question without an explanation about why it has been downvoted and voted to be closed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497287/how-do-i-connect-to-a-qnap .  Unsure what I did wrong.  Question is about accessing a NAS device from a Linux machine.

Comment: A solution could be quotas for downvotes. Max 4 pr week. Perhaps more if high reputation. Some see themselves as some sort of police or curators to keep the quality of questions high. Might stem from frustration of not being able to give constructive answers. (Of course some questions deserves to be downvoted. Badly written/unintelligible ones)

Comment: I've noticed, these past couple of months, what _looks_ like a systemic "close unclear" type of behaviour.  When I see these I'll most likely vote to keep open.  I have to wonder if someone has felt slighted by users of this site and is performing an active campaign to try and break it.

Comment: @oshirowanen if I had seen that question I'd probably have voted for closing because it looks more like a QNAP operational question than a Unix question, with the client not being specifically relevant.

Comment: @terdon Excellent point.  The system should could avoid much of that kind of retaliation by preventing a user who was downvoted publicly (ie, the downvoter left a comment) from downvoting any of that user's posts for 48 hours or something like that...

Comment: @Jonah The problem with your automatic retaliation cooldown block is that some of us comment on downvoted posts without downvoting ourselves. (I think I only have a critic badge on one site.) I personally don't think I've gotten downvoting retaliation, but that could just be due to the users seeing I don't have the critic badge on that site, so I couldn't have downvoted them. Are you suggesting someone who received any downvotes can't downvote my stuff for 48 hours after I comment on what I think they might do to improve their post? Because your comment doesn't read quite like that to me.

Comment: @EdGrimm I was saying that they wouldn't be able to downvote any person who had both downvoted them and commented.  Though honestly, the site is large enough that I don't think it would even matter if they were simply disallowed from downvoting anyone who had commented, period (if for some reason that was easier to implement).

Comment: @Jonah I'm not talking about ease of implementing. As a friendly helpful person who has only downvoted a single post in all of stack exchange as far as I can remember I would feel VERY left out if the protection you suggested was implemented as you suggested and I got retribution downvoting because either I'd tried to be helpful on Writing SE (the one place I found someone actually said something I felt was worth downvoting that one time) or because the person I'd tried to help didn't take the time to notice it couldn't have been me that downvoted them.

Comment: @EdGrimm I'm not following.  No matter which was it was implemented, you as a commenter who never downvotes would have either more protection or the same as you have today (ie, none).  But as I said, I think protecting *all* commenters would be a perfectly fine (and possibly better) strategy too.

Comment: @Jonah I understand I don't have that protection now. And, thus far, it's worked fine for me. But if you're putting in a system to protect the guilty who admit it, it would seem reasonable to have it protect the innocent who comment on a mission of mercy as well. I have not had the opportunity to comment on a heavily downvoted post on Writing SE since I found the one post to downvote. Heavy downvoting doesn't seem to be as much of a thing there, and it was a relatively recent thing. But the thing I'm asking is to just not put in one of your conditions, so it'd be easier to protect both.

Comment: @EdGrimm As I said in the last post, that's a perfectly reasonable request that I'd support.

Comment: I have seen questions with 5 down votes and not a single comment. That does not help the OP or even the other stupid readers to get a little less stupid by any mean and in that case if the down voter did not commented in fear of getting misunderstood, that should be the least significant reason. And at least the moderators should comment on it in that case. Even if one would do the kindest thing, some people will always get offended but is that a valid reason to stop doing that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also tend to comment when casting down- or close-votes, unless there are already comments that express my concerns.

There are many reasons why you might have received downvotes. It could be simply that the downvoter was having a bad day and didn't like your question. It could be that the downvoter was quickly scanning through several questions and didn't spare the time to write a comment. There's no way of knowing.

I get that it's frustrating to take even a small hit to your reputation, but I think there's 2 main things you can take away from the experience:

1. don't take it personally: it's not about you. It's possibly not even about your question.
2. take it as an opportunity to be self-critical about the question you wrote, and look for ways to improve it. The [Stack Overflow "how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page is full of good advice.

Comment: There are people who get a bit ... evangelical ... or maybe over-protective ... about the SO/SE Q&A format. I have received many downvotes that I think are undeserved, and I think one reason is that some people use them to punish people for providing answer to questions they think are "unworthy". Again, you just need to shake it off and move on with your day.

Comment: Today I learned that "evangelical" carries negative connotation.

Comment: Although I agree that "it's not about you", it should be about *the* question. "This question is not useful"

Comment: When you say "small hit" to reputation, keep in mind that the "small" is a relative term, and felt much more by @Yuki.kuroshita, at a rep of ~200, as opposed to one in your echelon with a reps 50,000+.  For someone who is trying to ask a good question, it's especially bothersome.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess would be that the downvotes may be due to the way the questions are scoped. Rather than ask for the best solution to accomplish the original goal, the questions instead ask how to make a particular solution work.  In both cases, the solution proposed is something that is contrary to industry practice. Some of the comments on the questions discuss some of these concerns, and suggest better ways of achieving the original goal, but the original questions are not being updated accordingly.  This can make it appear that the more standard suggestions are being discarded, which can lead to downvotes; everyone here is a volunteer, and wants to feel like their contributions are worth something.

A way to avoid the downvotes might be to edit the original question based on the new information you receive from comments and answers.  What people will often do is add an "**EDIT:**" or "**UPDATE:**" section at the bottom of the question body.  This allows them to maintain the original text for discussion and context while  acknowledging contributor ideas.

Comment: Okay. I usually clarify the questions in the comments. I will remember to integrate all the suggestions people say in the comments into my questions.

Comment: And in the question about .profile, my question, if you give it a thorough read (I admit it is very long) it is whether it is advisable to do something like that through script.

Comment: In the progress bar question, I thought my question was valid, as I wanted as general a solution as possible, like without installing anything extra. People did say that it would be difficult to do it, but it was possible as one person answered, which is the accepted answer. I realise that I should have added all the concerns people raised in the comments into the questions themselves.

Comment: I will edit the questions as required soon. And my point was exactly that I did not have a problem with the downvotes, my problem was with the lack of an explanation. This answer which you have given here, had it been present on the original questions, would have told me right then and there what was wrong and I would have made the questions better.

Comment: Regarding editing, I wrote [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5036/80216#5037) three months ago: … … «Imagine you wrote a paper for school, or a report for your job, and you got it back with a note “Not good enough — try again.”  Would you resubmit the same paper with corrections scribbled in the margins and a pile of yellow sticky notes on it?  Of course not.  You would rewrite the entire paper to be coherent, with a logical sequence and structure.  You would include all the information that needs to be there, probably just once, at an appropriate level of detail.»

Comment: Yes, as G-man said, please don't add "Edit" or "Update" sections! Just edit directly and re-write the question as though you had the information there from the beginning. There is no need to show what is new and what was there before, we have the edit history for that. The questions you post here might be read by someone many years later, and they don't need to know that this paragraph is an "Edit", they just need to be able to read the question clearly.

Answer (score 4):

@Yuki.kuroshita, I see nothing which would indicate you're violating forum conduct.

With that said, I've noticed there's an erosion of the experience across the Stack Exchange -- so you're not alone.  It's still better here though when compared to that cesspool of misinformation Spiceworks.

So just keep what you're doing.  Be a part of the community -- both ways:  helping others and getting help yourself.  If someone downvotes you, don't take it personally.  It's their problem and NOT yours.

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion here on SO meta, about mandating of feedback for downvotes:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Often you'll find that if you comment on your own question requesting an explanation for a downvote, you'll receive a useful reply.